# need help removing control buttons during animation

Tags: unity, animation

how to make it so that when the animation is played, when the control buttons are pressed, the direction of the animation does not change? the video shows how a person makes a roll, everything seems to be fine, but if I press A (left) or D (right), then he will turn in this direction during the animation, how to get rid of the control button during animation playback?
https://vimeo.com/manage/videos/687586757?embedded=true&source=video_title&owner=168640655

Comment: I can't say for sure without seeing your code. But you could try disable the A and D on roll button pressed and enable A and D when roll is complete.

Comment: Exactly, that has nothing to do with the animation component or animation clips. You can add an event at the start and the end of your roll animation so your program knows when to disable other buttons